# How to find out the given latitude and longitude are coming under specified area?

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using this code http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/test.html 
for the selection of the area on google map. After selection I am getting all the list of latitudes and longitudes of the selected area. The problem is I have latitude and longitude of one point, I want to find out that point is coming under the selected area or not using PHP.

Thank You guyz for your reply. 
I got the perfect answer here 
    [Find Point in polygon PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065039/find-point-in-polygon-php)

Comment: A latitude/longitude pair defines a point, so can you define what you mean by "**the** latitude and longitude ... under specified area"?

Answer (score 3):

If i am not misunderstood, you are trying to find selected point (lat, lon) is in area of 4 other point (lat,lon) sort of like this case;

```
  Ax,Ay              Bx,By
A(10,20)           B(20,20)
+-----------------+
|         Px,Py   |
|        (15,15)  |
|       P         |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
  Cx,Cy              Dx,Dy
C(10,10)           D(20,10)
```

you can find this information matematically
A, B, C, D is the corner points of rectangle and P is a single point what you looking for. 
Here is the code piece which can help you to find P is in square or not.

**PS: Code is not written in editor, so it may contain typo or error. Please check carefully.**

```
function isInsideSquare($Ax, $Ay, $Bx, $By, $Cx, $Cy, $Px, $Py) {
    if (triangleArea($Ax,$Ay,$Bx,$By,$Px,$Py)>0 || triangleArea($Bx,$By,$Cx,$Cy,$Px,$Py)>0 || triangleArea($Cx,$Cy,$Dx,$Dy,$Px,$Py)>0 || triangleArea($Dx,$Dy,$Ax,$Ay,$Px,$Py)>0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function triangleArea($Ax, $Ay, $Bx, $By, $Cx, $Cy){
    return ($Cx*$By-$Bx*$Cy)-($Cx*$Ay-$Ax*$Cy)+($Bx*$Ay-$Ax*$By);
}
```

Comment: thanx man thats what im looking for, I will check it now and tell you.

Comment: i tried it but isInsideSquare function always returning me "false".

Comment: thanx for ur help. i got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065039/find-point-in-polygon-php