# Point inside polygon weird results

Tags: php, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

I want to determine if coordinates are inside a polygon, however I'm getting extra results that are not in the polygon. It's almost like it only checks for if EITHER the lat or lon is in range but not both. Any ideas??

```
     public function subcacheClients (){
      $clients = gzfile('tmp/whazzup/cache/clients.txt.gz');
      for($i=1;$i<count($clients);$i++){
           $clients[$i] = explode(':', $clients[$i]);
           //polygon of Canada
           $polylat = array(90,82,77,75,65,64,61,53,49,45,45,42,47,47.33,45,45,43.63,43.5,42.83,41.63,41.85,42.33,42.5,43.58,45.33,48,49,49,48.42,48.18,48.5,48.33,5,54,54.83,59.5,60.32,90);
           $polylon = array(-141,-60,-75,-76,-57.75,-63,63,-54,-51,-51,-53,-67,-67.75,-69.33,-71.5,-75,-76.92,-79.2,-78.93,-82.5,-83.06,-83.03,-82.5,-82.12,-82.5,-88.33,-95.0,-123.33,-123.12,-123.35,-124.83,-128,-133.75,-136,-130,-135,-141,-141);

           $inpolygon = $this->inPolygon($clients[$i][5], $clients[$i][6], $polylat, $polylon);
           if($inpolygon == true && $clients[$i][5]>0 && $clients[$i][6]<0 && $clients[$i][3]=='ATC'){
                echo $clients[$i][0];
                file_put_contents('tmp/whazzup/cache/controllersOnline.txt', implode(':', $clients[$i]), FILE_APPEND);
           }
      }
 }
 public function inPolygon($lat, $lon, $polylat, $polylon) {
      $j = count($polylat)-1;
      $result = false;
      for($i=0;$i<count($polylat);$i++){
           if($polylat[$i]<$lat && $polylat[$j]>=$lat
           || $polylat[$j]<$lat && $polylat[$i]>=$lat){ //if the latitude at the beggining is bigger than and at the end is smaller than or vise versa
                if($polylon[$i]+($lat-$polylat[$i])/($polylat[$j]-$polylat[$i])*($polylon[$j]-$polylon[$i])<$lon){ //
                     $result = true;
                }
           }
           $j=$i;
      }
      return $result;
 }
```

Comment: There is working code for this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818567/point-in-polygon-algorithm-giving-wrong-results-sometimes/18190354#18190354

Comment: I dont wanna make a class like that due to my file/class structure in my framework, I wanna keep it simple, my code is/looks much simpler just a small problem somewhere in it