# i want to find my lat long in a particular area coordinates arrays in php

Tags: php, json, geolocation

I want to find my lat-long exist or not in a particular area in PHP

Area coordinates JSON array ->

```
{"lat":[21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.38641226905212,21.38129726211495,21.376182076389874,21.371066711911467,21.365951168714215,21.36083544683268,21.355719546301387,21.350603467154897,21.34037077315456,21.33525415836984,21.33013736510819,21.31478591480751,21.30966840798403,21.304550722856618,21.29943285945987,21.289196597996938,21.2840782,21.27895962387228,21.27384086964844,21.268721937363132,21.263602827051027,21.268721937363132,21.268721937363132,21.27384086964844,21.27895962387228,21.2840782,21.289196597996938,21.294314817828436,21.30966840798403,21.31990324329242,21.33013736510819,21.33525415836984,21.34037077315456,21.345487209427773,21.350603467154897,21.355719546301387,21.36083544683268,21.371066711911467,21.376182076389874,21.38641226905212,21.39152709716691,21.39664174642479,21.401756216791277,21.406870508231872,21.41198462071206,21.41198462071206,21.406870508231872,21.401756216791277],"lng":[40.44953843828125,40.45503160234375,40.46601793046875,40.47151109453125,40.48799058671875,40.49348375078125,40.49897691484375,40.50447007890625,40.50447007890625,40.50996324296875,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.50996324296875,40.50447007890625,40.49897691484375,40.48249742265625,40.47700425859375,40.46601793046875,40.46052476640625,40.45503160234375,40.44953843828125,40.43855211015625,40.42756578203125,40.41657945390625,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.41108628984375,40.42207261796875,40.42207261796875,40.42756578203125,40.42756578203125,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.44404527421875,40.44953843828125,40.45503160234375,40.46601793046875,40.47700425859375]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_decode` in php for this. You can find more on the function [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

    $latsToCheck = array(
        // ENTER LATITUDES HERE THAT YOU NEED TO CHECK
    );

    $langsToCheck = array(
        // ENTER LONGITUDES HERE THAT YOU NEED TO CHECK
    );

    $str = '{"lat":[21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.39664174642479,21.38641226905212,21.38129726211495,21.376182076389874,21.371066711911467,21.365951168714215,21.36083544683268,21.355719546301387,21.350603467154897,21.34037077315456,21.33525415836984,21.33013736510819,21.31478591480751,21.30966840798403,21.304550722856618,21.29943285945987,21.289196597996938,21.2840782,21.27895962387228,21.27384086964844,21.268721937363132,21.263602827051027,21.268721937363132,21.268721937363132,21.27384086964844,21.27895962387228,21.2840782,21.289196597996938,21.294314817828436,21.30966840798403,21.31990324329242,21.33013736510819,21.33525415836984,21.34037077315456,21.345487209427773,21.350603467154897,21.355719546301387,21.36083544683268,21.371066711911467,21.376182076389874,21.38641226905212,21.39152709716691,21.39664174642479,21.401756216791277,21.406870508231872,21.41198462071206,21.41198462071206,21.406870508231872,21.401756216791277],"lng":[40.44953843828125,40.45503160234375,40.46601793046875,40.47151109453125,40.48799058671875,40.49348375078125,40.49897691484375,40.50447007890625,40.50447007890625,40.50996324296875,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.51545640703125,40.50996324296875,40.50447007890625,40.49897691484375,40.48249742265625,40.47700425859375,40.46601793046875,40.46052476640625,40.45503160234375,40.44953843828125,40.43855211015625,40.42756578203125,40.41657945390625,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.40559312578125,40.41108628984375,40.42207261796875,40.42207261796875,40.42756578203125,40.42756578203125,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.43305894609375,40.44404527421875,40.44953843828125,40.45503160234375,40.46601793046875,40.47700425859375]}';

    $result = json_decode($str, true);

    if (in_array($latsToCheck, $result['lat']) && in_array($langsToCheck, $result['lng'])) {
        echo "co-ordinates exist";
    } else {
        echo "co-ordinates doesn't exist";
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
$latlngInfo = 'your lat lng json data';
$arrMixLatLang = json_decode($latlngInfo, 1);

// to check its available or not
if(in_array('lat value', $arrMixLatLang['lat']) && in_array('lng value', $arrMixLatLang['lng'])){
    //Your statement
}

// to get index
$latindex = array_search('lat value', $arrMixLatLang['lat']);
$lngindex = array_search('lng value', $arrMixLatLang['lng']);
```

Comment: i found this Script and it's working for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065039/find-point-in-polygon-php