# Check if a Polygon is inside another Polygon in PHP

Tags: php, geometry, polygon

I'm trying to make an algorithm in PHP that should return true if the area of a polygon cross the area of another one, or if it's fully inside.

[Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) is the kind of algorithm i'm looking for but I'd need it in php.

Here is the pseudo code from wikipedia:

```
List outputList = subjectPolygon;  

  for (Edge clipEdge in clipPolygon) do
     List inputList = outputList;
     outputList.clear();
     //
     for(int i = 0 ; i < inputList.count ; i += 1) do
        Point current_point = inputList[i];
        Point prev_point = inputList[((i % inputList.count) + inputList.count) % inputList.count];

        Point Intersecting_point = ComputeIntersection(prev_point,current_point,clipEdge)

        if (current_point inside clipEdge) then
           if (prev_point not inside clipEdge) then
              outputList.add(Intersecting_point);
           end if
           outputList.add(current_point);

        else if (prev_point inside clipEdge) then
           outputList.add(Intersecting_point);
        end if

     done
  done
```

My polygons are in fact saved by latitude and longitude coordinates but I dont think this would result in any problem for an algorithm.

Do you think that it is possible for me to do what I described ? 
Or if it's not, what is my logical mistake please?

Another question is : If I have a polygon with all borders inside another polygon, it will never cross it. So will the algorithm work in that case?

Have a nice day !

---

UPDATE 03/04/2019

I've found a pretty nice tool named [geoPHP](https://geophp.net/) which uses GEOS library. I've installed it on my server and it works partially.

Here is my Testing code :

```
         if (geoPHP::geosInstalled()) {
            print "GEOS installed :)<hr>";
          }
          else {
            print "GEOS not installed :(<hr>";
          }

        $polygon = geoPHP::load('POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 1))','wkt');
        $area = $polygon->getArea();
        $centroid = $polygon->getCentroid();
        $centX = $centroid->getX();
        $centY = $centroid->getY();
        print "Polygon 1: <br>";
        print "Area: ".$area." <br> Center :  X=".$centX." and Y=".$centY;

        $polygon2 = geoPHP::load('POLYGON((2 2,2 3,3 3,3 2,2 2))','wkt');
        $area = $polygon2->getArea();
        $centroid = $polygon2->getCentroid();
        $centX = $centroid->getX();
        $centY = $centroid->getY();
        print "<hr>Polygon 2: <br>";
        print "Area: ".$area." <br> Center :  X=".$centX." and Y=".$centY;

        print "<hr>";

        if($polygon2->crosses($polygon)){
            print "IT CROSSES";
        }else{
            print "IT DOESN'T CROSSES";
        }
```

It should cross, but the `$polygon2->crosses($polygon)` method returns false, I can't understand why ...

Here is the result I get :

[image: Result of this code]

I Hope i'm on the good way, I'd like to understand why I can't use the "crosses" method I find on [this documentation](https://geophp.net/api.html#user-content-geometries)

Comment: all depends about how you will implement `ComputeIntersection` method in the pseudo code, because at the moment you have only the logic to going through all Polygone's Edges

Comment: Yes I came here to find help on the realization of this algorithm and to make the ComputeIntersection method in order to make it work fully

Comment: The shape of the Earth will give you trouble if a polygon includes a pole or crosses the 180th meridian

Comment: My polygons will never be that big and they only concern France

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065039/find-point-in-polygon-php/5065219#5065219

Comment: @benJ Thanks a lot but I've already seen it and that works only if points are inside the polygon, but you can imagine two polygons with no points inside each other but with a superposition of areas !

Comment: I've edited my post to show you guys what I did since yersterday, and where I am actually stuck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how to solve all my problems !

1. Going to https://geophp.net/ and downloading sources
2. Installing the package php-geos following this link https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/amd64/php-geos/download
3. Enabling the php-geos package (geos.ini)
4. The method "crosses" was not the one I was looking for ! The good one was "**intersects**"

The right code is :

```
         include("geophp/geoPHP.inc");

         if (geoPHP::geosInstalled()) {
           print "GEOS installed :)<hr>";
         }
         else {
           print "GEOS not installed :(<hr>";
         }

        $polygon = geoPHP::load('POLYGON((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))','wkt');
        $area = $polygon->getArea();
        $centroid = $polygon->getCentroid();
        $centX = $centroid->getX();
        $centY = $centroid->getY();
        print "Polygon 1: <br>";
        print "Area: ".$area." <br> Center :  X=".$centX." and Y=".$centY;

        $polygon2 = geoPHP::load('POLYGON((2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 3, 2 2))','wkt');
        $area = $polygon2->getArea();
        $centroid = $polygon2->getCentroid();
        $centX = $centroid->getX();
        $centY = $centroid->getY();
        print "<hr>Polygon 2: <br>";
        print "Area: ".$area." <br> Center :  X=".$centX." and Y=".$centY;

        print "<hr>";

        if($polygon2->intersects($polygon)){
            print "OK";
        }else{
            print "NOT OK";
        }
```